# Comparing std::variant type instances

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
struct A{};
struct B{};
typedef std::variant<A, B> Record;

Record Get() {
    return Record {A()};
}

void Test() {
    if (Get() == Record{A()}) {

    }
}
```

I get an error:

> In instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::operator==<A, B>' no matching function for call to object of type 'std::__1::equal_to'

Why I have an error and how can I compare the result of function with `Record{A()}` ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to check? Do you want to know what type the returned variant contains?

Comment: @cigien It is  a minimal example to reproduce my error. I am writing unit test to test my function `Get`, which returns different variants of `Record`.

Comment: I don't think you can do this unless you are able to do `if (A() == A())` right?

Comment: Is [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/holds_alternative) what you're looking for by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide equality operators for every type the `std::variant` can hold.

```
bool operator == (A const &lhs, A const &rhs) {
    return true;
}

bool operator == (B const &lhs, B const &rhs) {
    return true;
}
```

Full example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rjTfqE

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do? From this code it looks like you're trying to just see if the variant returned from `Get()` contains an `A`. In that case you'll want `std::holds_alternative` like this.

```cpp
#include <variant>

struct A{};
struct B{};

using Record = std::variant<A, B>;

Record Get() {
    return Record {A()};
}

void Test() {
    if(std::holds_alternative<A>(Get())) 
    {
        int i = 0;
    }
}
```